# How can I edit a .dat file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to:

- edit the data of a .dat file on my computer for a website.
- pull data from the file to use it later on.

I know a tiny bit about javascript and heard javascript cannot directly edit databases.

Is a .dat file in my computer a database?

I have done a few things in Javascript for websites but I haven't done anything complicated completely myself. I created some websites before and I have a basic understanding of HTML and CSS.

Please phrase your response as simply as possible. Explain the meaning of any complicated but necessary terms.

Comment: Have you downloaded the entire file locally to your computer? If you have the file  you can edit the .dat file using any text editor, right click then open with, if you have a data that has video pdf etc you have to have a adobe reader or any type of media player. Once you open it you can edit it.

Comment: A .dat file could contain many things in many (and potentally entirely arbitrary/proprietary) formats. There are lots of basic tutorials out there for building a simple database-driven website, but writing one is outside of StackOverflow's scope.

Answer (score 1):

You need some server-side script to access the filesystem of the server such as PHP or NodeJs...

You can reference this url.

Nodejs example here.

[w3school link here.](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_filesystem.asp)

```
let fs = require('fs');
```

Appeding file:

```
fs.appendFile('mynewfile1.txt', 'Hello content!', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Saved!');
});
```

Delete file:

```
fs.unlink('mynewfile2.txt', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('File deleted!');
});
```

Rename file :

```
fs.rename('mynewfile1.txt', 'myrenamedfile.txt', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('File Renamed!');
});
```

Read file :

```
fs.readFile('demofile1.html', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP server code to resolve your problem.

Here is PHP file I/O example code.

File reading:

```
<?php
   echo file_get_contents("test.txt");
?>
```

File writing :

```
<?php
   echo file_put_contents("test.txt","Hello World. Testing!");
?>
```